RESTHeart MongoDB bulkWrite
I am exploring the capabilities RESTHeart offers for interacting with MongoDB.
Is there a way to perform a bulkWrite operation? I'm referring to the MongoDB bulkWrite method, which allows a single batch operation to include a mix of different types of operations (like insertOne, updateOne, updateMany, replaceOne, deleteOne, and deleteMany) as shown in the example below:
db.collection.bulkWrite(
   [
      { insertOne: <document> },
      { updateOne: <document> },
      { updateMany: <document> },
      { replaceOne: <document> },
      { deleteOne: <document> },
      { deleteMany: <document> }
   ],
   { ordered: false }
)

In the RESTHeart documentation, it mentions bulk write capabilities, but it seems to primarily refer to operations like insertMany or updateMany.
Would it be a good idea to write a RESTHeart plugin in Java to enable true bulk write functionality?
I tried what's here in the docs.

The RESTHeart MongoDB plugin provides a RESTful API to interact with data, where each URL identifies a resource, and the HTTP verb specifies the operation to be performed.
To perform bulk write operations on documents, use the following request:
POST /coll [ {}, {}, {} ]
The type of MongoDB operation is determined by the ?wm=insert/update/upsert query parameter:

UPDATE -> bulk write consisting of one ReplaceOneModel per document in the request array
UPSERT -> bulk write consisting of one ReplaceOneModel with upsert option per document in the request array
INSERT -> bulk write consisting of one InsertOneModel per document in the request array

To bulk delete documents, use:
DELETE /coll/*?filter={ "qty": {"$gte": 10 } }
This operation leverages the DeleteManyModel class.
To bulk update documents, use:
PATCH /coll/*?filter={ "qty": {"$lte": 10 } } { "a": 1, "b": { "$qty": 10 }}
This operation leverages the UpdateManyModel class.
These requests, along with the single-document operations POST /coll {}, PATCH /coll/docid, and DELETE /coll/docid, cover 99% of common use cases.
For more specialized needs, a custom plugin can be implemented. For example, you could create a plugin that accepts an array of _ids to bulk delete documents using DeleteManyModel.
